# Custom Dropdown menu mouseleave issue

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div's one contains "clickable div" and other "nav_menu" which is menu.
There is a mouseleave function implemented for "#clickable_div" my problem is
when i hover over the menu it should not slideUp which is currently happening
How can i fix this ?

Note : I'm using a small plugin for dropdown

JSFiddle - > http://jsfiddle.net/HtNK3/13/

### Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visible = false;

    $('#clickable_div').click(function() {
      visible = true;
      $('#nav_menu').showMenu({
            parent:'#clickable_div'
      });                
    }).mouseleave(function() {

    if(visible) {
        visible = false;
        window.setTimeout(function(){$('#nav_menu').hide('blind');}, 1000);
    }
    });       //end mouseleave     

    $('#l1').click(function() {
    alert("...");               
    });  
});
```

Comment: Your code is working exactly as its supposed to. Its just not what you want. So, what do you want exactly?

Comment: when i click the div , menu show's up. When i move the mouse over the menu it should not close up..which is happening currently.

Answer (score 2):

> my problem is when i hover over the menu it should not slideUp which is currently happening How can i fix this ?

Then don't hide the box on mouseleave. Remove all this:

```
.mouseleave(function() {

    if(visible) {
        visible = false;
        window.setTimeout(function(){$('#nav_menu').hide('blind');}, 1000);
    }
 })
```

EDIT:

The simplest way I could think of is to wrap the whole thing inside another block element and bind the `mouseleave` event to that. I've updated your Fiddle to show the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/HtNK3/20/

Comment: well i want it to hide out but not when the mouse is over the menu or when the mouse is over the "clickable_div".

Comment: Then, say that in your question. That's what I meant by "What do you want to do exactly?". Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is causing problem,

```
     .mouseleave(function() {
        if(visible) {
            visible = false;
            window.setTimeout(function(){$('#nav_menu').hide('blind');}, 1000);
        });
```

What you are trying to do is when the mouse leave the menu header your are asking to hide the menu.

> Try to detect mouse out on both the menu header and menu. [Check this
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928632/how-to-detect-mouseout-of-two-elements-in-jquery) on how to do that

[Js Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Bdpnd/)

There are lot of [plugins](http://http:http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions///) already available to do this take any one of them and change the css to match your site